# How to remove html fragment from one page with thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have an html fragment that it included in a Layout. this layout exists in all the pages. now I have just one page that I want to exclude this fragment from it.

Layout page :

```
<div th:replace="~{chat/head.html :: head}"></div>
<div th:replace="~{chat/footer.html :: footer}"></div>
```

all pages: includes the Layout.
Last pages : include the Layout without :

```
<div th:replace="~{chat/footer.html :: footer}"></div>
```

Comment: "I have an html fragment" where?? Give more detailed examples

Comment: I have a Layout page that includes a fragment of headers and a fragment of footer that appear in all the pages of my application. now I want to remove the header just from one html page how can I exclude it

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Your latest edit seems to be more helpful already! But it is important to keep this in mind: [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593). And maybe read [the Thymeleaf documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html)

Comment: You can have some condition to include or exclude

Comment: @soorapadman there is no th:exclude in thymeleaf. And how can i use **th:if** in this case to test if its equals my URL page to exclude the fragment ?

Comment: Oops i didn't meant that way . I had same require requirement where prelogin dont wanna show header part . so i have done using `isAuthenticated` .

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be add a flag to the layout page:

```
<div th:replace="~{chat/head.html :: head}"></div>
<th:block th:if="${!#bools.isTrue(hideFooter)}">
    <div th:replace="~{chat/footer.html :: footer}"></div>
</th:block>
```

Then on the server:

```
@GetMapping("/thatOnePageThatDoesntNeedAFooter")
public String getThatOnePage(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("hideFooter", true);
   return "thatOnePageThatDoesntNeedAFooter";
}
```

The logic may seem a little strange, but this would alleviate the need for adding a variable to the model in every other case but this exceptional one.

Note that you would need to put the `th:if` outside the `th:replace` block.  `th:replace` would take precedence over `th:if` if you put them on the same line.

Comment: Don't crucify me if it's off - I wrote it up off the cuff without an IDE